# How to run a connection command that follows a database query in Docker

Tags: docker

I'm editing a deployment script that should execute some commands inside my database container.

This script must execute a command which performs a connection to databse inside the container followed by creating a databse.

Once the connection is done the seconde command is not executed.

```
docker exec -it db bash -c "mysql -u admin -pPassword && CREATE DATABASE test;"
```

So how can I perform the two commands in the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any one who try to find a solution here is it

```
docker exec -it db bash -c "mysql -u admin -pxxxx -e'CREATE DATABASE test'"
```